# SSIS Destination Timeout

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Here is my setup:

- DEV:  SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, 32-bit OS/SQL
- PROD: SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, 64-bit OS/SQL

I have 20 very simple data flows in my package. ADO Source to ADO Destination only, no transformations between. The package simply pulls data off an Informix server and writes to SQL Server.

NB:

- Source query is dynamic driven by expression.
- The source connection string is dynamic (the DSN changes as there are 2 Informix servers).
- Destination table is dynamic driven by expression.

All of my testing went well, and the package runs without issue. This was running on DEV, writing to the DEV SQL Server instance.

I copied the SSIS to PROD (no changes), left the SQL Server connection pointed at the DEV SQL Server instance, and it ran fine.

Then, when I pointed the PROD SSIS as the PROD SQL Server instance, the destinations started to timeout on very small data sets (< 5K rows).

> [ADO NET Destination [148]] Error: An exception has occurred during
>   data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding.

To see if this was a SQL Server issue, I pointed the DEV SSIS at the PROD SQL Server instance, and it ran fine.

To recap:

- DEV SSIS writing to DEV SQL Server (localhost) -- Fine.
- PROD SSIS writing to DEV SQL Server (network) -- Fine.
- DEV SSIS writing to PROD SQL Server (network) -- Fine.
- PROD SSIS writing to PROD SQL Server (localhost) -- Poor.

The slow performance is only seen when running on PROD and writing to the PROD SQL Server instance.

I have tried changing a couple destinations from ADO to OLEDB (had to add conversion from DT_WSTR to DT_STR for OLEDB destination) and they too timeout in the latter scenario.

I am completely stumped, and need some guidance troubleshooting this. I realized I can increase the timeout from the default 30 seconds, but that doesn't seem like a great solution.

Comment: Can you get your DBAs and Network team involved?   This sounds to me more like a server/network issue and not a programming issue.

Comment: @TabAlleman I can yes, but without me pointing them in a direction, I can already picture the response.  That said, this seems related to the Informix driver, not SQL Server.  As a test, I setup an entirely new package with just a dataflow task pulling a table from Informix to SQL Server.  I saw the delays as noted above; but when I changed the source to SQL Server (diff box, but a mirror of the same table), it was fast!  The Informix driver is 32-bit, I wonder if that is the true root cause.

Comment: Are you pulling from the same Informix Server/Database when you use both DEV and PRD SSIS packages?

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes... and my simple test package writes to DEV SQL Instance in 2 seconds; so maybe its not the 32-bit driver on PROD after all.

Comment: Testing from PROD writing to a different 2008 box also shows time outs, but from PROD to another 2008 R2 does not!

Comment: I have tested this to 7 other SQL servers, 3 of which are 2008, the rest are 2008 R2 (through 2016), and only the 2008 boxes are timing out... but oddly, they don't time out if the sending server is 2008 R2!

Comment: I was a little suspicious when I saw the different in 2008 and 2008 R2.   It's never a good idea to have different versions of SQL Server in DEV vs PRD.

Comment: @TabAlleman  Agreed, but my little test package was designed entirely on PROD in this case, and its timing out to all 2008 instances.  I just found an old SQL 2K box we have an old legacy DTS on, and tried writing there, it times out!  This seems to be a very peculiar bug that only impacts this Informix source/driver and Pre-2008 R2 destinations.  My word, I've been at this for 5 hours, I need a drink.  Thank you for hashing this out with me!